# Host .net web API to public access

Tags: c#, .net, webapi

I have a problem I can't host a my web API to public access. For Example, someone from outside to do some requests and get a response. I tried with IIS configuration, all samples try from the GTS, and then there is no movement. Can anyone post me full specs what I need to do to have for example
https://myipaddress:5001/api/ping
visible on public and someone from another machine can execute this request and get a response.

Comment: What you have is networking issue. SO is for programming problems. If you don't have the expertise to do this then I caution against it because if you get it wrong you risk serious security issues.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>IIS is meant for local development.</strike> What you want to do is to `publish` your application. There are many hosting providers, but if we stick to Microsoft, you can use Azure to publish your application:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/quickstart-dotnetcore?tabs=net60&pivots=development-environment-vs

It is paid, however you can register to get temporary free access to test the solution.

Comment: IIS is not just for local development. It is the web server you use when you host on Windows. Are you thinking of IIS Express?

Comment: AFAIK local IIS hosts in background and you can access sites running on it without running your IDE, unlike Express. I think if question is about allowing public access to 'your IP' is denoted, it would be way safer for OP to publish the app rather than expose your local IIS to external access. I agree the IIS is not only meant for local development, but I would recommend other ways to exposing API publicly.

Comment: Azure app services use IIS when you select a windows service plan. I agree it would be safer hence my comment.